# How can i check if location is in my radius?

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

i trying to get if location is in my radius.
i.e I have my current location "LatLng" object and i have one more "LatLng" object and i want to check if the two object are in rang of 1km?
How can i implement that?

Answer (score 4):

**In `Location.distanceBetween()` function provide you distance in meters and float value ..**

> distanceBetween(double startLatitude, double startLongitude, double
>   endLatitude, double endLongitude, float[] results) Computes the
>   approximate distance in meters between two locations, and optionally
>   the initial and final bearings of the shortest path between them.

use this it working i've already checked it  .....

```
       float[] dist = new float[1];

                Location.distanceBetween(firstLoaction.latitude,firstLoaction.longitude,anotherLocation.latitude,anotherLocation.longitude,dist);

      if(dist[0]/1000 > 1){
        //here your code or alert box for outside 1Km radius area 
       }
```

**NOTE:- For getting the location distance always use `Location.distanceBetween()` which is provide by ANDROID .**

Answer (score 2):

```
double distanceInKiloMeters = (currentLocation.distanceTo(someLocation)) / 1000; // as distance is in meter

if(distanceInKiloMeters <= 1) {

// It is in range of 1 km
}
else {

// not in range of 1 km
}
```

Comment: What is the someLocation? can i set dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

you can try converting LatLng to Location object for both first and then using distanceTo method to find the distance between those two and check if it is 1km or not

Answer (score 0):

distanceto methode to get distance from locCenter and point and just substitute this distance from the radius if <0 so the point out of range , else the point in border or inside the range.. good luck